# Checking and unchecking checkboxes with dynamic ids and class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox, nested-checkboxes

I have a grid that has grouping i.e the grid shows products of group. So, the structure has Group and its childs. Same way I will have some other groups and their childs which I am binding like below.I want to check and uncheck the entire sublist on the click of parent.

```
CSHTML
@{
    if (Model.List.Count() > 0)
    {
    <table>
        <tr>
              <input type="checkbox" class="cls@(obj.GroupId)" name="@obj.GroupId" onclick="checkUncheckAll(this.class)" />
            <td>Name</td>
          </tr>
        @foreach (var obj in Model.subList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="cls@(obj.GroupId)" name="@obj.GroupId" /></td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @obj.Name
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    }
}


<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="PickAllCheckedRows();" />
```

I have been trying to do this like below but no success. Also I want to pick all the checked group and its subitems on click of save button. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkUncheckAll(sender) {
        alert(sender);
        var chkElements = document.getElementsByClassName('chkItems');
        for (var i = 0; i < chkElements.length; i++) {
            chkElements[i].checked = sender.checked;
        }
    }

  function PickAllCheckedRows() {
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling your function passing in `undefined` because you're passing `this.class`:

```
onclick="checkUncheckAll(this.class)"
```

Elements don't have a `class` property (they do have `className`), and if they did, you dont' want to pass its *class*, you want to pass the element itself since you're using it as `sender.checked`.

Just remove the `.class` from the call.

If you're trying to do all *within a group*, then you'll need to use `className` in the function when getting the other checkboxes to check/uncheck:

```
function checkUncheckAll(sender) {
    var chkElements = document.getElementsByClassName(sender.className);
    // Note ------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
    for (var i = 0; i < chkElements.length; i++) {
        if (chkElements[i] !== sender) {             // Not strictly necessary I guess, but...
            chkElements[i].checked = sender.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

That assumes you'll only ever have a single class on the "all" checkboxes.

Comment: this is working . As i click on parent checkbox, its childs are getting checked and on uncheck the parent, childs are also getting unchecked but If I check each subitem one by one, its not checking the parent checkbox.

Comment: @Sweetie: Yup, you have to implement that separately, handling clicks on the individual item checkboxes and setting the "all" checkbox based on whether they're all selected.